# run php script in background and never die linux

Tags: php, linux, process, mqtt

I have a php script that use Mosquitto client. I am using putty SSH to access to the server. I want to run the php script in background continously even when I disconnect from putty. I have tried screen and nohup but it stop when closing putty window

Thank you

Comment: Have you heard the name cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
nohup php script.php &
```

So you run script in background and disconnect the process from the terminal. If it doesn't help, try `disown` command after it. There is a [good answer with detailed explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) of differences between these commands.

To get full control of your script, a good choice would be a `System V` init script. There is a template at https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template, which you can use.

Copy template to `/etc/init.d` directory and rename it. In template you need to change variables:

```
dir="/your/working/directory"
cmd="nohup php script.php"
user="your user"
```

Doing that you will be able to control your script by

```
/etc/init.d/your_script start
/etc/init.d/your_script stop
```

Make sure you have permissions to write in `/var/log/` and `/var/run/`, or   run script as `sudo`(leave `user=""` empty)

Comment: thank you I find it. It is the same solution as yours. Now how to stop this process? I used  ps -ef |grep nohup  but the problem that the PID always change so every time I try to kill it , it say that the PID doesn't exist

Comment: @user3921905, I've added a solution to control script using standard UNIX mechanics

Answer (score 1):

Using `screen` is a much better solution than nohup.

screen let's you name sessions and rejoin them later so you don't need to resort to using ps to find your backgrounded applications

You can start a named `screen` session like this

```
screen -S [session name]
```

Which you can detach from with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd> then reattach with

```
screen -r [session name]
```

You can also start a session with a command in the background with

```
screen -dmS [session name] [command]
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html